# db2 dynamic sql with select into clause in anonymous block

Tags: sql, db2, dynamic-sql, select-into

I am working on a DB2 SQL code.

I need to get the count of records from a list of tables. The table details will be fetched from a cursor with select.
To get the count of records I have been trying with a `SELECT INTO` statement. Since the table names will be varying, I am using a dynamic SQL code. 
I am sharing the piece of code that I have been trying. 
I am not quite sure of the syntax while using DB2 `SELECT INTO` and Dynamic SQL combination. I am getting the following error with the below attempt.

Can anyone tell me why this is so? If possible, appreciate if you could share a working code of DB2 select into and dynamic sql.

`SQL0104N  An unexpected token "statmnt2" was found following "SET statmnt2 := 'set ? = (SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbn".  Expected tokens may include:  "".`

---

```
DECLARE
indbnm                  VARCHAR(30);
intblnm                 VARCHAR(30);
v_errorText             varchar2(50);
statmnt2                VARCHAR(1000);
VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU       CHAR(1);
stmt1                   STATEMENT;
statmnt2                VARCCHAR2(100);

BEGIN

indbnm := "db2inst5";
intblnm:= "rules";

SET statmnt2 := 'set ? = (SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbnm||'.'||intblnm||' FETCH FIRST 1 ROWS ONLY)';
PREPARE stmt1 FROM statmnt2;
EXECUTE stmt1 into VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU ;


DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE(VAR_COD_TIPO_ARQU);
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
            v_errorText :=SUBSTR(SQLERRM,1, 1024);
            DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('FAILED WITH MESSAGE: '||v_errorText);

END;
```

Comment: Is the typo "VARCCHAR2" in your code or in the sample above?

Comment: Hi @data_henrik you are correct. It was in my code. I correct it, but still am facing the same error.      Error message "SQL0104N  An unexpected token "statmnt2" was found following "SET statmnt2 := 'set ? = (SELECT COD_TIPO_ARQU FROM '||indbn".  Expected tokens may include:  ""."

Comment: From my research in the web I got some inputs that I need to use PREPARE with an OUTPUT clause, and then the EXECUTE with an INTO statement. I haven't got the proper syntax of it yet, although I spent quite some time looking for it. I will be happy if anyone could share a successfully working example DB2 code which uses SELECT INTO with Dynamic SQL for a variable tablename.

Comment: You are mixing up SQL PL and PL/SQL syntax in the same procedure, which is not supported. Choose one.

Comment: I haven't worked much on DB2. Could you please share a sample DB2 PLSQL code which uses SELECT INTO clause along with DYNAMIC SQL. I just need the right syntax which works. I am trying to get count of records from a set of tables (which will vary) for each set of conditions. For condition X, the tables to check might be ,say 2, and for Condition Y, the list will be a different set of tables. There are about 11 conditions.